# Use custom BibLaTeX fields with Org-ref

Tags: org-mode, bibtex, org-ref

I am managing my bibliography with John Kitchin's `org-ref` package. I want to create an `@film` entry type with a few custom fields. So in my `init.el` file, I have:

```
;; Create fields for Film type
(add-to-list 'bibtex-biblatex-field-alist
  '(("director" "Director(s) of a film, video or DVD title")
    ("producer" "Producer of the film title")
    ("distributor" "Distributor of a film title")))

;; Setup Film type
(add-to-list 'bibtex-biblatex-entry-alist
  '("Film" "Film, video or DVD"
    ("title" "year" "type")
    nil
    ("director" "producer" "distributor" "address")))

;; Use BibLaTeX to process your bibliographies
(bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex)
```

Now the question remains as to how I should tell `org-ref` that "director" and "producer" should be treated as authors and "distributor" should be treated as a publisher, when producing the citation?

For the author aliases, the BibLaTeX Manual recommends something like this:

```
\DeclareLabelname{%
  \field{director}
  \field{producer}
}
```

But adding `#+latex_header: \DeclareLabelname[film]{\field{director}\field{producer}` to my `org` document does not have any effect?

Is there perhaps another `bibtex.el` variable I should customize?

Comment: I don't think you have to tell org-ref anything. All the citation generation is done by biblatex/biber. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175776/how-can-i-create-entirely-new-data-types-with-biblatex-biber for a full answer on how to do this.

Comment: If it is the tooltips you are referring to, these are generated inside org-ref. See comments at the end of https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues/482 for how to customize these.

Comment: As a side note, are your `add-to-list`s working here as expected? I had some trouble with this in a similar approach in the past https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454966/105447