# Org-ref with biblatex - is it feasible or should bibtex be preferred?

Tags: helm, bibtex, org-ref, helm-bibtex

I am contemplating setting up org-ref to use within org mode for drafting scientific texts. However, as  I go through various blogs etc. on the subject, it seems that org-ref is tailored for the bibtex-format. Also, I expect to use helm, which also seems to be targeting bibtex.

I believe I will need the UTF-8 encoding of biblatex, as I will work with sources from different languages. But I am in doubt if I should try to bend around the limitations of the bibtex format because org-mode is tailored for that - or try to make org-ref bend around the biblatex-format instead. Any pros and cons to these approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The underlying formats for bibtex and biblatex are very close.  I am not familiar with `org-ref`, but the comments on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51855/2710 suggest that it understands biblatex out of the box.

Comment: Andrew thank you for your insight! I think you are right. However, the maintainer of the org-ref package states here: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/05/13/Using-org-ref-for-citations-and-references/ that the package was written with bibtex in mind - I am wondering what setup makes most sense here.

Comment: Either way should work. Bibtex is much more tested, but as far as I know standard biblatex works fine too.

Comment: @JohnKitchin thank you very much for your time!! And your huge efforts into helping everyone out with your programming. If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Org-ref supports standard bibtex and biblatex as far as I know. So far neither of those has been a limitation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will add any useful experiences here when I have my setup with biblatex ready.